# Deep-learning: Storing the outputs of hidden layers python keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning

I have built my model and I found a way storing the output of the desired hidden layer. The code is the following:

```
layer_name = 'add_28'
intermediate_layer_model = Model(inputs=model.input,
                             outputs=model.get_layer(layer_name).output)
intermediate_output = intermediate_layer_model.predict(X_train)
```

I just wanted to ask if those outputs are those that occur after the training process. And if not is there a way of doing it?
Thank you

Comment: These lines are present after fit or before?

Comment: I used them after the training

Comment: Then yes,outputs are those that occur after the training process.

Comment: Thank you very much! If you want write it as answer to give you an upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your doing it once you have fit the model, then, of course, outputs are those that occur after the training process.